Databricks: Python User Defined Function to concat the values of few columns along with None inside a DataFrame
I have multiple DataFrames including values such as
DataFrame1 (df1):
EmpId  FirstName   LastName MiddleName  
1        Anna       Walter    I
2        Jack                 Shaun
3        Andrew     Hill

I need to combine values for FirstName, LastName, MiddleName as:
Anna|Walter|I
Jack||Shaun
Andrew|Hill|

DataFrame2 (df2):
DeptId   DeptName   Category Contact  Building
10       Arts         1       James     7
20       Science      2         
30       Social               Kim       4

I need to combine values for DeptName, Category, Contact,Building as:
Arts|1|James|7
Science|2||
Social||Kim|4

I need a user-defined function that I can call in the similar lines of:
fields1 = F.array('FirstName', 'LastName', 'MiddleName')
df1.withColumn('Combination1', udf_xyz(fields1))

fields2 = F.array('DeptName', 'Category', 'Contact', 'Building')
df2.withColumn('Combination2', udf_xyz(fields2))

I tried a function as:
def concatdf_ws(df, colName, fields):
    df = df.fillna('')
    df = df.withColumn(colName, concat_ws('|', fields))
    df=df.select(*[when(trim(df[x])=='',None).otherwise(df[x]).alias(x) for x in df.columns])
    df.display()
    return df;

But filling each null column with '' and replacing again back seems very costly way as we have millions of records.
Is there a better way to do it.

Can you just write those columns as csv with a | separator?

You can use the user-defined function below to concatenate values with a pipe ('|') delimiter and handle null values:
def udf_xyz(fields):
    def concatdf_ws(*args):
        values = [arg if arg is not None else '' for arg in args]
        return '|'.join(map(str, values))
    
    return F.udf(concatdf_ws)

Call the UDF with the required details like below:
fields1 = ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'MiddleName']
fields2 = ['DeptName', 'Category', 'Contact', 'Building']

df1 = df1.withColumn('Combination1', udf_xyz(fields1)(*fields1))
df2 = df2.withColumn('Combination2', udf_xyz(fields2)(*fields2))

Print the data frames, and you will get the columns Combination1 and Combination2 as shown below:

Update:

Thank you. However this works with fields1 = ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'MiddleName'], but in our case we have F.array('FirstName', 'LastName', 'MiddleName'). It doesn't work for F.array. Is there a way to get it work for F.array.

You can use the user-defined function below to concatenate values with a pipe ('|') delimiter and handle null values:
 def udf_xyz():
    def concatdf_ws(*args):
        values = [arg if arg is not None else '' for arg in args[0]]  # args[0] is the array
        return '|'.join(map(str, values))
    
    return F.udf(concatdf_ws)


    
    

Call the UDF with the required details like below:
fields1 = F.array('FirstName', 'LastName', 'MiddleName')
fields2 = F.array('DeptName', 'Category', 'Contact', 'Building')

df1 = df1.withColumn('Combination1', udf_xyz()(fields1))
df2 = df2.withColumn('Combination2', udf_xyz()(fields2))


Thank you. However this works with fields1 = ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'MiddleName'], but in our case we have F.array('FirstName', 'LastName', 'MiddleName').  It doesn't work for F.array.  Is there a way to get it work for F.array.

@Nanda I have updated my answer please check it once.
